# Changing formula content based on ComboBox value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a ComboBox which searches through a determined Range and replace a content from all formulas. Example:

Current Value from ComboBox is "MAI"

`=COUNTIFS('CNAEs Inválidos MAI'!A:A;C8)`

The user select from the ComboBox the value "JUN" and the vba function replaces it to:

`=COUNTIFS('CNAEs Inválidos JUN'!A:A;C8)`

The search and replace only works once, because I cannot get the current value from the ComboBox to search.

So far this is what I have:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Range("A1:R53").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=ComboBox1.Value, Replacement:=ComboBox1.Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
        Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Is there a way to get the ComboBox current value and the ComboBox new selected value?

Comment: Look at the `INDIRECT` worksheet function first `=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'CNAEs Inválidos " & combo value & "'!A:A";C8)` along these lines

Comment: Thank you for the help Nathan, I will try. Another question, please: How do I get a ActiveX ComboBox value without using vba? The 'combo value' works?

Comment: @RafaelTorres - if you want to ask another question go ahead and start a new question :)

Comment: @RobinMackenzie No problem. Thought it was related to the problem. Thanks

Comment: Do you need an ActiveX ComboBox per se? Otherwise use a Form control and just set the Input Range and and output range. Use the output range combined with a lookup function to get the text values again and use `Indirect` formula to get the result you need.

Comment: `Indirect` with Form control did the trick. Thank you all!

Comment: I'll add this as answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `INDIRECT` worksheet function first `=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'CNAEs Inválidos " & combo value & "'!A:A";C8)` along these lines

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an `ActiveX ComboBox` per se?

Otherwise use a `Form control` instead. 
In the Form control formatting, set the Input Range and and Output cell. 
Input Range will take your text values (MAI, JUN, etc.)
Output cell will display the selected index (1, 2, etc.) in the dropdown.

Use the output cell value in a lookup function to get the text values again from the Input Range. Then use the `Indirect` formula to get the resulting formula you're after.